# Weex: page show correct in web but incorrect in iOS device

Tags: ios, flexbox, weex

I use weex to start a project, and the login.vue is like:

```html
<template>
  <div class="login">
    <div class="images">1
    </div>
    <div class="centerPart">2
    </div>
    <div class="agree">3</div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}
.login :first-child{
  height: 250px;
}
.login :last-child{
  height: 200px;
}
.images {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.centerPart{
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.agree {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: coral;
}
</style>

<script>

</script>
```

When I run `npm start`, it shows like what I want in the browser:
[image]

However, when I run `weex run ios`, the simulator show a blank page:
[image]

I also try it in the device, and it shows a blank page, too.

So just wonder why it comes blank in the simulator and how can I find out the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weex doesn't support the complete `flex` shorthand syntax yet. You can only specify the `flex-grow` part.

In your example, use `flex: 1;` in `.centerPart` and it should adjust its height.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add this in your style

```
width: 750px;
flex: 1;
```

750px is the width of all device and weex used flex layout default